# How I can add picture background in android opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to put my background as a picture rather than color.

Comment: Please clarify your question: provide a broader description, add relevant code samples. It's impossible to guess what problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a full viewport textured quad with the background image as texture before everything else with depth and stencil writes turned off.